# How to use Tuckey urlrewrite in spring boot to access service using ?wsdl

Tags: web-services, spring-boot

My clients wanted to access wsdl using ?wsdl notation, but the springboot service i have created is working with only '.wsdl' format. I need a working example/sample how to configure Tuckey urlrewrite in the springboot application.
I have tried using below code, but the application complaints as it cant find urlrewrite.xml (which i have placed in src/main/resources folder.

Q1: How can i make my service to be accessible using url below
http://localhost:8080/ws/organisation?wsdl

I have tried using below code, but tuckey cannot find the urlrewrite.xml which is under src/java/resources.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean tuckeyRegistrationBean() {
    final FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new ilterRegistrationBean();
    registrationBean.setFilter(new UrlRewriteFilter());
    registrationBean.addInitParameter("confPath", "urlrewrite.xml");
    return registrationBean;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I could figure out a solution. This is now reading `urlrewrite.xml` from the src/main/resources folder.

No need to declare above mentioned bean definition in the question post (`public FilterRegistrationBean tuckeyRegistrationBean()`), as the below code declared as `@Component` will automatically register with context and url-rewriting is performed.

```
@Component
public class WsdlUrlRewriteFilter extends UrlRewriteFilter {

    private static final String CONFIG_LOCATION = "classpath:/urlrewrite.xml";

    @Value(CONFIG_LOCATION)
    private Resource resource;

    @Override
    protected void loadUrlRewriter(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        try {
            Conf conf = new Conf(filterConfig.getServletContext(), resource.getInputStream(), resource.getFilename(), "");
        checkConf(conf);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new ServletException("Unable to load URL-rewrite configuration file from " + CONFIG_LOCATION, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please paste your sample xml file? Somehow with my xml file it is not working.

Comment: @Javadroider, try something like this: `<urlrewrite use-query-string="true">
<rule>
    <from>/lbs/lbsService[\?]+wsdl</from>
    <to>/ws/lbsService.wsdl</to>
</rule></<urlrewrite>` -  assumes you mapped SOAP stuff to `/ws` - I found that less confusing.

Comment: @Javadroider you will probably also need another rule for any `xsd` files that are involved.

Answer (score 4):

Best option is to write your own filter as follows.You can make use of HttpServletRequestWrapper to handle the ?wsdl extension and let the server handle the request.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class WSDLQuestionMarkReplaceFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        //put init logs
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        if ("wsdl".equalsIgnoreCase(httpRequest.getQueryString())) {
            HttpServletRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(httpRequest) {
                @Override
                public String getQueryString() {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public String getRequestURI() {
                    return super.getRequestURI() + ".wsdl";
                }
            };
            chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, response);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        //put destroy logs
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### It worked for me. Hope it works for others too. SpringBoot+JAR

Please use the following dependency

---

```
         <dependency>
           <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
           <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
           <version>4.0.4</version>
         </dependency>
```

---

Created urlrewrite.xml in resource folder

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE urlrewrite
    PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite3.0.dtd">

<urlrewrite>
<rule>
    <name>Domain Name Check</name>
    <condition name="host" operator="notequal">www.userdomain.com</condition>
    <from>^(.*)$</from>
    <to type="redirect">http://www.userdomain.com$1</to>
</rule>
```

---

Added in main ApplicationRunner.java

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean tuckeyRegistrationBean() {
    final FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registrationBean.setFilter(new CustomURLRewriter());
    return registrationBean;
}
```

---

And created a CustomURLRewriter

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.Conf;
import org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter;
import org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter;
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class CustomURLRewriter extends UrlRewriteFilter {
private UrlRewriter urlRewriter;

@Autowired
Environment env;

@Override
public void loadUrlRewriter(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    try {
        ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource("urlrewrite.xml");
        InputStream inputStream = classPathResource.getInputStream();
        Conf conf1 = new Conf(filterConfig.getServletContext(), inputStream, "urlrewrite.xml", "");
        urlRewriter = new UrlRewriter(conf1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ServletException(e);
    }
}

@Override
public UrlRewriter getUrlRewriter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
    return urlRewriter;
}

@Override
public void destroyUrlRewriter() {
    if(urlRewriter != null)
        urlRewriter.destroy();
}
}
```

Comment: Need some help over here please.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55411311/redirect-non-www-url-to-www-url-in-spring-boot

Comment: sorry about the late response. I saw you were able to solve it. Good luck