# WSDL (dot) vs. (question mark) notation in SpringBoot WS

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-boot, wsdl

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.1 to build a contract first web service.

I followed Spring-boot sample examples -

https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/.

And this worked fine.

My wsdl is now located at

```
http://localhost:8080/ws/countries.wsdl
```

Problem is that the application that will be the consumer of this web service requires the wsdl url to be written as

```
http://localhost:8080/ws/countries?wsdl
```

As per post I integrated turkey UrlRewriteFilter
[How to use Tuckey urlrewrite in spring boot to access service using ?wsdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40540942/how-to-use-tuckey-urlrewrite-in-spring-boot-to-access-service-using-wsdl)

But, URL rewriting is not happening as expected. My `urlrewrite.xml` looks like this. From logs I found out that it is taking xml file but not doing url rewrite. Where am I going wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite
        PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite3.0.dtd">

<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
        <from>/countries?wsdl</from>
        <to>/countries.wsdl</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

Answer (score 9):

I found best solution.Write your own filter as follows.You can make use of HttpServletRequestWrapper to handle the ?wsdl extension and let the server handle the request.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class WSDLQuestionMarkReplaceFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        //put init logs
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        if ("wsdl".equalsIgnoreCase(httpRequest.getQueryString())) {
            HttpServletRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(httpRequest) {
                @Override
                public String getQueryString() {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public String getRequestURI() {
                    return super.getRequestURI() + ".wsdl";
                }
            };
            chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, response);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        //put destroy logs
    }
}
```